# MySQL unknown error (SELECT, LEFT JOIN, AS...)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables ProductCategory and Sale. I have to return **product_id** where category is A, and **qty** sold without discount. MySQL didn't compile for my codes below. Would someone please help? Thank you so much.

```
SELECT pc.product_id, s.non_disc_qty
FROM productcategory pc
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT (SUM(qty) AS non_disc_qty
  FROM sale
  WHERE discount = 0
  GROUP BY product_id) AS s
  USING (product_id)
WHERE category = "A";
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide the error message you got from MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery that you join to `productcategory` must also return `product_id` because this is the column that the join is based on.
Also you have an unnecessary opening parenthesis before `SUM(qty)`.
Change to this:

```
SELECT pc.product_id, COALESCE(s.non_disc_qty, 0) non_disc_qty
FROM productcategory pc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, SUM(qty) AS non_disc_qty
  FROM sale
  WHERE discount = 0
  GROUP BY product_id
) AS s USING (product_id)
WHERE pc.category = 'A';
```

I used `COALESCE()` so that you get `0` instead of `null` in the results of `non_disc_qty` for the products that don't have a match in the join.

Another way to do what you want is with a correlated subquery instead of the join:

```
SELECT pc.product_id, 
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(s.qty) FROM sale s WHERE s.discount = 0 AND s.product_id = pc.product_id), 0) non_disc_qty
FROM productcategory pc
WHERE pc.category = 'A';
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.